# Maximum and minimum of integers in python using none type

Tags: python

Am using Python 2.7 .I tried  initializing smallest and largest to none and then split the if's into 2 conditions.
The problem is the smallest is always none. I don't get the minimum of the numbers entered. What is going on here?

```
largest=None
small=None


while True:
 num = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
 if num == "done" : break
 else:
  n1=int(num)

  print largest
  n1= int(num)
  print small
 if n1 <small:
  small=n1

 if n1> largest:
  largest=n1


print "Maximum", largest
print "Min", small
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Provide code as mentioned and edit your post so it makes a little more sense.

Comment: @user5058765 Please do watch your coursera videos and do your assignments yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2.7 , the issue is that if you compare an `int` with `None`, `None` would always be smaller than any int. Example to show this -

```
>>> -100000000000 < None
False
```

What you would need to do is to put a condition like -

```
if small is None:
    small = n1
elif small > n1:
    small = n1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [sys.maxint](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.maxint) instead of `None`:

```
import sys

largest=-sys.maxint-1
smallest=sys.maxint
```

Since you want the first number to to be largest and smallest, make largest initially the smallest int possible -- in the case `-sys.maxint-1` Converse is true with smallest -- make that `sys.maxint`

Btw, you cannot compare and int and None on Python 3.

Comment: Just a side note on Python 3

Comment: Figured it out! Thank You

Answer (score 0):

```
def maxmin():
    largest = None
    smallest = None
    while True:
        numar = input("Enter a number: ")
        if numar == "":
            break

        numar = int(numar)

        if largest is None:
            largest = numar
            if smallest is None:
                smallest = numar
        else:
            if numar < smallest:
                smallest = numar
            if numar > largest:
                largest = numar
    print("Maximum is", largest, '\nMinimum is', smallest)

maxmin()
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Semantically you dont need the line "if smallest is None:", as the first element read is by defintion the smallest and largest so far. But as someone has already said I think posting complete solutions to Coursera assignments goes against their honor code!